# During Chef converge cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I'm facing issue with Chef deprecation errors. I have 3 cookbooks say A, B & C. For cookbook A, B is dependency and C is dependency for B. In one of the recipes in cookbook B I have the following

```
from_file 'xxxxxx' do 
  source 'yyy' 
  mode 0xxx 
  owner 'abc' 
  group 'abc' 
end
```

In one of the recipes in cookbook C I have the following which is same.

```
from_file 'xxxxxx' do 
  source 'yyy' 
  mode 0xxx 
  owner 'abc' 
  group 'abc' 
end
```

Now, when I converge cookbook A it is failing with cloning resource errors failed due to deprecation.

Please suggest how should I change this to represent in Chef 13.

Answer (score 0):

`from_file` is not a chef resource, but rather internal mixing (maybe you were referring to [`file` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html).

with that being said, it feels like you are facing [resource cloning deprecation message (chef-3694)](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html), which is deprecated since chef 10.18.0 and was removed in chef 13.

to fix that, give your resources unique names. for instance: if you have two resource with the same names as below

```
file 'x' do
  # ...
end

file 'x' do
  # ...
end
```

then change one of them so you will have a unique name:

```
file 'x' do
  # ...
end

file 'y' do
  # ...
end
```